# How to get start and end time of event in popover message from an event in FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, momentjs, popover

I want to display the `start` and `end` times from each event as a `popover` message when the mouse hovers over the event in `monthView` of `FullCalendar`.

I  have the following:

```
element.popover({
    content: event.start,
    animation: true,
    delay: 300,
    content: event.start + event.end,
    trigger: 'hover',
    placement: 'top',
    container: 'body'
});
```

When I have either `event.start` or `event.end` in `content`, I get the `date` and `time` correctly in the following way: `Wed May 09 2018 08:00:00 GMT +0000`. But when I have `event.start + event.end` in `content`, I am getting a vague number: `3051738000000`.

Say if `start` is `09:00:00`, and `end` is `15:00:00`. I want the message to say:

```
Start: 9AM
End: 3PM
```

What should I do?

Comment: See http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/ for how to format your dates and choose the format you want. `start` and `end` are both momentJS objects. I think what you're seeing there with the `+` is that it assumes it's a mathematical operation and adds together the total number of milliseconds represented by both dates. You need to specifically format the date into a string to ensure you get what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I took a look at it and it indeed helped. However, I have one small query, I have got the `start` and `end` in the right format, but I need a `linebreak` in between so that the `start` and `end` are displayed on two different lines. This is what I have so far...
`content: '<p>' + 'Start: ' + event.start.format('h:mm a') + '</p><p>' + 'End: ' + event.end.format('h:mm a') + '</p>'` The output for this is: `<p>Start: 8 am</p><p>End: 5 pm</p>

Comment: Solved it @ADyson. I had to put `html: true`. I will post the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format for `start` and `date` needs to be in the correct manner. [Displaying format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) shows the correct `format`. Thank you @ADyson for the link! (see comments). Also, to enable `html` in the content, we need to set `html: true,`.

```
element.popover({
    animation: true,
    delay: 300,
    trigger: 'hover',
    placement: 'top',
    html: true,
    container: 'body',
    content: '<p>' + 'Start: ' + event.start.format('h:mm a') + '</p><p>' + 'End: ' + event.end.format('h:mm a') + '</p>'

});
```